# How use find method to model

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have actionView($id) method in my controller. And have 2 models Posts and User and I want to get one posts(with user['name']). I have main gridview a when clicked for item have url like that:
http://localhost/test/basic/site/1
last 1 it's a this $id parameter. 
Now my method is:

```
public function actionView($id)
   {
       if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
       {
           return $this->redirect(['login']);
       }
       else
       {
        $data = Posts::find($id)->joinWith('user');
        return $this->render('detail',['data'=>$data]);
       }
    }
```

but I have error:

```
Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\DetailView::0
```

Comment: in which controller refers ActionView code?   .  and please updated  your question and add your Post model code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the relation in your Posts-Model like this:

```
 public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

After that you can get the User with this:

```
Posts::find($id)->with('user')
```

You can find it in the documentation:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Comment: I'm trying to do like that but have an error
Getting unknown property: yii\db\ActiveQuery::id

Comment: @Rosti, can you debug to see which line the error occured? In controller or in view. And whether the data has successfully queried from DB, if it's the case we can assume the error is in view.